# Using C to determine if a string contains any imbalanced brackets

Tags: c, string

I am completing some course work and stuck at this final hurdle! I need to identify if a string contains any bracket imbalances, but I can only use C. I have read that this is a very popular interview question used by some organisations. I have a solution, but I know it is not correct, the answer requires using the stack to push and pop variables. Does anyone have any advice? I appologies for my naivety.

Here is my solution:

```c
int balanced(char line [LINE_LENGTH])
{
    int bracketCount = 0;
        
    for (int counter = 0 ; counter < strlen(line) ; counter++)
    {
        if (line[counter] == '[' || line[counter] == ']' || line[counter] == '(' || line[counter] == ')' || line[counter] == '{' || line[counter] == '}')
        { 
            bracketCount++;
        }
    }
    return bracketCount;
}
```

Comment: Using `strlen()` will make this whole function O(n^2)

Comment: If you know you should use a stack, have you tried to use one? What is your problem with that? Your solution has multiple flaws. You must  distinguish different types of brackets. `"((]]"` is not OK. Also you don't care about correct sequence, i.e. `"))(("` is also not OK. And also your return value does not make sense. If you get balanced brackets you will return `0`. For a function called `balanced` one would expect to get some `true`'ish value if the brackets are balanced. You should read about using a stack and start over again. You cannot do this with your approach.

Comment: I understand my approach is not the right approach, I was trying to return the amount of brackets counted, then % 2 to see if their was a remainder. The reason I haven't tried to use the stack is simply because I don't know how

Comment: List examples for valid & invalid brackets strings.

Comment: also no need to use strlen, use a pointer instead `for (char* p=line;*p;++p) {}`

Comment: @Darth-CodeX: you are right in theory and `strlen` is definitely not needed, but with optimisations enabled, both **gcc** and **clang** are able to determine that `line` is not modified in the loop hence pure function `strlen` can be called just once: https://www.godbolt.org/z/G579ezjY5

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, calling `strlen()` even once is not needed  just check `str[i] != '\0'`

Comment: @Fredrik `[ { ] }`

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is incorrect: you increment `bracketCount` for both types of brackets, so the function just returns the total number of brackets, it does not check for proper balancing.

You could improve your approach by incrementing `bracketCount` for opening brackets and decrementing it on closing brackets: this would detect missing brackets but not imbalance nor mismatched brackets.

You could use different counters for `{`, `[` and `(` and keep track of bracket types separately, but you still would not detect nesting errors as in `"([)]"`

To implement a proper checker, you need to store the opening brackets in a stack where you can check for each closing bracket that it matches the currently open one.

Here is a simple implementation using an array of `char` as a stack:

```
int balanced(const char *line) {
    char brackets[LINE_LENGTH];
    char *bp = brackets + LINE_LENGTH;

    *--bp = '\0';
    for (size_t i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char cc;
        switch (line[i]) {
          case '[':
            cc = ']';
            break;
          case '(':
            cc = ')';
            break;
          case '{':
            cc = '}';
            break;
          case ']':
          case ')':
          case '}':
            if (*bp == '\0') {
                /* stack is empty: unexpected closing bracket */
                printf("offset %zu: no opening bracket for '%c'\n",
                       i, line[i]);
                return 0;
            }
            if (*bp != line[i]) {
                /* nesting error: closing bracket does not match the expected type */
                printf("offset %zu: bad bracket type for '%c', expected '%c'\n",
                       i, line[i], *bp);
                return 0;
            }
            bp++;
            continue;
          default:
            continue;
        }
        if (bp == brackets) {
            /* stack overflow */
            printf("too many open brackets\n");
            return -1;
        }
        *--bp = cc;  /* push the expected closing bracket */
    }
    if (*bp) {
        /* some opening brackets have not been closed */
        printf("missing brackets: %s\n", bp);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;    
}
```

Here is a much simpler recursive approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *check_brace(const char str[], int endc) {
    while (str) {
        int c = *str++;
        switch (c) {
          case '(': str = check_brace(str, ')'); break;
          case '[': str = check_brace(str, ']'); break;
          case '{': str = check_brace(str, '}'); break;
          case ')':
          case ']':
          case '}':
          case '\0': return (c == endc) ? str : NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int balanced(const char *line) {
    return check_brace(line, '\0') != NULL;
}

int main() {
    char str[80];
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        printf("%d\n", balanced(str, '\0') != NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach to find out if a string of brackets is balanced or not.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline char match_bracket (const char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
    case '{' : return '}';
    case '}' : return '{';
    case '(' : return ')';
    case ')' : return '(';
    case '[' : return ']';
    case ']' : return '[';
    default:
        fprintf (stderr, "\nERROR: %c is not supported\n", ch);
        exit (1);
    }
}


/**
 * Opening Brackets : [ { (
 * Closing Brackets : ] } )
 * Balanced : No overlapping of brackets & every open has a matching close
 * Example :    {[({})]} - balanced
 *              {[(}{)]} - unbalanced
 * Function returns on first detection of any error
 */
int check_bracket_balance (const char* brkts, const int slen)
{
    if (!brkts || ! (*brkts) || slen < 0) {
        printf ("\tInvalid arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }
    const char* open_brackets = "([{";
    const char* close_brackets = ")]}";

    char bStack [slen + 1]; // array stack emulation
    int sTop = -1;
    for (int bi = 0; bi < slen; ++bi) {
        if (strchr (open_brackets, brkts[bi]))
            bStack[++sTop] = brkts[bi];                 // push on to stack
        else if (strchr (close_brackets, brkts[bi])) {  // a closing bracket
            if (sTop < 0) {  // empty Stack
                printf ("\tExpected %c before %c at %d\n", match_bracket (brkts[bi]), brkts[bi], bi + 1);
                return 1;
            }
            if (bStack[sTop] == match_bracket (brkts[bi])) // is stack-top a matching bracket
                --sTop;     // pop matching bracket from stack
            else {
                printf ("\tExpected %c before %c at %d\n", match_bracket (bStack[sTop]), brkts[bi], bi + 1);
                return 2;
            }
        } else {
            printf ("\tInvalid char %c at %d\n", brkts[bi], bi + 1);
            return -2;  // use enums like eInvBracketChar for easier code-read
        }
    }
    if (sTop >= 0) {
        printf ("\tThere are %d unmatched opening brackets\n", sTop + 1);
        return 3;
    }
    return 0; // balanced
}


#define MAX_STRINGS 8
int main ()
{
    char* strings[MAX_STRINGS] = {"{([])}",
        "{}()[]",
        "{})([]",
        "{([)]}",
        "{{(([[",
        "",
        "{}<>{}",   // assuming <> are invalid
        "Testing"
    };
    printf ("\n");
    for (int si =0; si < MAX_STRINGS; ++si) {
        printf ("\n%s\n", strings[si]);
        int error = check_bracket_balance (strings[si], strlen (strings[si]));
        if (error)
            printf ("\tERROR[%d]: Brackets not Balanced\n", error);
        else
            printf ("\tBrackets Balanced\n");
    }

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you reject non bracket characters in the string? `"{}<>{}"` seems OK, the question does not mention any such constraint.

Comment: I am obviously not the downvoter, someone seems to resent us providing solutions for this interview question instead of giving mere hints.  My take is newbie programmers learn from good examples if they are motivated. If not, mere hints will not help anyway.

Comment: I wonder what you are trying to achieve with `int ich = (unsigned) brkts[bi];`?  If you want to avoid indexing an array with a negative index value on systems where the `char` type is signed, you should write `int ich = (unsigned char)brkts[bi];`

Comment: use `stdbool.h`

Comment: @Darth-CodeX: for what purpose do you suggest using `<stdbool.h>`? The code posted does not use boolean values.

Comment: @chqrlie return `1` and `0`, using true and false will make it consistent with C++

Comment: @Darth-CodeX: `is_closing_bracket` and `is_opening_bracket` could indeed be defined as returning `bool`, but there is no obligation in C nor in C++ and the OP says *I can only use C*. `check_bracket_balance` returns `0` for a balanced string and an error code otherwise: not a candidate for a boolean return value.